# Хендлер для запрета ссылок

Tags: python, telegram, бот, aiogram, handlers

Не могу найти хендлера для запрета ссылок в телеграм группе.

```
@dp.message_handler(IsGroup(),Command("url_false", prefixes="!/"), AdminFilter())
async def media_false_handler(message: types.Message):
    member = message.reply_to_message.from_user
    member_id = member.id
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    
    await message.chat.restrict(user_id=member_id, can_add_web_page_previews=False)
    await message.reply_to_message.delete()
    await message.chat.restrict(can_send_media_messages=False, user_id=member_id)
    await message.answer(f"Foydalanuvchi <i><b>{message.reply_to_message.from_user.get_mention(as_html=True)}</b></i>"
                         f"\n{time} daqiqa havola jo'natish huquqidan mahrum qilindi!"
                         f"\n<b>Iltimos, qoidalarimizga amal qiling!</b>")

    service_message = await message.reply("Xabar 5 soniyadan so'ng o'chib ketadi.")
    # 5 sekun kutib xabarlarni o'chirib tashlaymiz
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await message.delete()
    await service_message.delete()
```

Comment: а как вопрос связан с приложенным кодом?

Comment: извиняюсь, забыл удалить одну строчку. 

 "await message.chat.restrict(can_send_media_messages=False, user_id=member_id)"

Comment: мне вот честно совсем ничего не понятно, улучшите вопрос